# Testing Custom Grails Taglib with Service and Plugin Dependencies

Tags: unit-testing, testing, grails, plugins, integration-testing

I have a custom taglib that needs to make calls to a service method, which in turn uses the [Wslite plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/wslite) to send and receive SOAP messages. The taglib looks something like this.

```
class myTagLib {
    def myService
    def thisTag = {
        def parametersFromService = myService.method("argument")
        out << render(template:'/myFolder/myView',
        model:parametersFromService)
    }
}
```

I'm trying to construct a test for this taglib. My test is something like:

```
void testThisTag() {
    def appliedTagLib = applyTemplate('<thisTag attr="value" />')
    def parametersFromService = myService.method("argument")
    def renderedTemplate = render(template:'/myFolder/myView',
        model:parametersFromService)
    assertEquals appliedTagLib, renderedTemplate
}
```

I started by writing this as a Unit test. I tried the simple `MockFor(MyService)` annotation, as well as [mocking them in a more elaborate fashion](http://blog.freeside.co/post/41774569512/wiring-taglib-dependencies-in-unit-tests), but `myService` object was always null when the taglib tried to invoke it.

Given that, I decided it best to simply do this as an integration test; that would get me access to the plugin and service, no problemo.

However, the applyTemplate method only works if your test class extends the GroovyPagesTestCase. If you do *that* though, the render method doesn't work, at least not in an integration test. I know that applyTemplate and render *do* work alongside each other in a unit test for a taglib, as I've tested other taglibs this way.

I seem to be between a rock and a hard place. To get access to the service, plugin, and the SOAP service they invoke, I need an integration test. To use the applyTemplate() method, I need to extend the GroovyPagesTestCase, but that breaks the render method. I've tried adding `import grails.test.GroovyPagesTestCase` to my test class, and then invoking the applyTemplate method off of it, but that results in a missing method exception.

Thoughts?

The Grails version is 2.0.1, but I could upgrade to 2.2.1 if that would help (our site is in transition).

---Addendum-----
elias suggested that I could inject an instance of grails.gsp.PageRenderer to get a working render method. I've tried constructing one:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPagesTemplateEngine
import grails.gsp.PageRenderer
```

...

```
def pageRenderer
```

...

```
void setUp() {
    context = grailsApplication.mainContext
    taglib = context.getBean(myTagLib.class.name)
    pageRenderer = new PageRenderer(new GroovyPagesTemplateEngine(context.getServletContext()))
}
```

But receive this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method findTemplateByPath() on null object
at grails.gsp.PageRenderer.renderViewToWriter(PageRenderer.groovy:120)
at grails.gsp.PageRenderer.render(PageRenderer.groovy:77)
at MyTagLibIntegrationTests.testThisTag(MyTagLibIntegrationTests.groovy:37)
```

Comment: You don't need to initialize it in setUp, just use the correct bean name for the instance, `def groovyPageRenderer` and it should do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, what I ultimately did was to extend the GroovyPagesTestCase in order to get applyTemplate, then inject the groovyPageRenderer as elias suggested. Persnickity note: you must call your injected PageRenderer groovyPageRenderer in order for spring to do all the appropriate wiring for you. So my test class finally looked like:

```
class myTaglibIntegrationTests extends GroovyPagesTestCase {
    PageRenderer groovyPageRenderer 
    def imageService
    @Test
    void testThisTag() {
        def appliedTagLib = applyTemplate('<thisTag attr="value" />')
        def parametersFromService = myService.method("argument")
        def renderedTemplate = groovyPageRenderer.render(template:'/myFolder/myView',
            model:parametersFromService)
        assertEquals appliedTagLib, renderedTemplate
    }
}
```

Comment: See elias's answer here for another helpful idea of hacking up a test for a taglib that may work better in other scenarios:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/17113855/1524502

Answer (score 6):

I was struggling with something similar some days ago, here is how I solved it:

1. Keep the test as in integration test (don't need to extend anything)
2. Grab the instance of the taglib bean with `grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean`
3. Test it using a method call

And that's it! :)

```
class MyTagLibTests {
    def grailsApplication
    def taglib

    @Before
    void setUp(){
        // grab the taglib instance from Spring context
        taglib = grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean(MyTagLib.class.name)
    }

    @Test
    void myTestAboutThisTag() {
        def thisTagArgs = [:] // set up the arguments here
        assert 'shouldResultThis' == taglib.thisTag(thisTagArgs).toString()
    }
}
```

Comment: That is helpful, but manually defining a string to compare against makes me sad like Old Mammoth. I'm going to see if I can find some way to make the render method available so that I can compare against that.

Comment: Right! I think you can inject an instance of `groovyPageRenderer` in your test, and try to use its render method.

Comment: ...but if I could do that, why not just extend the GroovyPagesTestCase and compare applyTemplate()'s output to render()'s? See my edit on trying to inject the pageRenderer. This may just be a failure on my part to do basic dependency injection correctly.

Comment: Well, I think you can do that, but it will still only work for a taglib that only renders a template. I offered my approach as a more general solution for an integration test for taglibs.

Comment: And it _was_ very helpful, especially the groovyPageRenderer comment, which got me on the right track. Since the goal in this particular question was to compare a taglib's output against a rendered template, I can't quite accept it as the answer, but I'll try to give credit where credit is due. :)

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner solution would use the GroovyPageUnitTestMixin as it already contains a render method.

```
@grails.test.mixin.TestMixin(grails.test.mixin.GroovyPageUnitTestMixin)
class myTaglibIntegrationTests {

    def myService

    @Test
    void testThisTag() {
        def appliedTagLib = applyTemplate('<thisTag attr="value" />')
        def parametersFromService = myService.method("argument")
        def renderedTemplate = render(template:'/myFolder/myView', 
                                      model:parametersFromService)
        assertEquals appliedTagLib, renderedTemplate
    }
}
```

A good write-up on some simple taglib testing can be found here: http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2013/05/grails-goodness-testing-views-and.html